# How do i include the env() method inside of a min or max function in SCSS?

Tags: sass, environment-variables

I have a `styles.scss` file.

In it, i have the following definition which fails to compile down to css:

```
.modal-dialog {
  margin-top: max(6%, env(safe-area-inset-top));
}
```

I get the following error:

```
"env(safe-area-inset-top)" is not a number for "max"
```

How do i write this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.modal-dialog {
   margin-top: unquote('max(6%, env(safe-area-inset-top))');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `calc(max(6%, env(safe-area-inset-top)))`?

Comment: I appreciate the response, but as noted, i needed to solve the error and was not looking for an alternative way to define the style.